# Print data from mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to mastery php by reading book, and i'm stuck on this code :

```
$title_db_query = "SELECT zagolovok FROM Title WHERE id = 5"; 
$title_query = mysql_query ($title_db_query);  
while($row_title = mysql_fetch_array($title_query))
{  
    echo $row_title['zagolovok']; 
}
```

This code supposed to print data from 'zagolovok', but instead it gives nothing. I tried to use `var_dump($title_query)` and it says `bool(false)`.

I have connection to db, because other queries are work fine.

Comment: Enable error reporting. If $title_query returns false: you have an error. Read more here: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
You might also consider using mysqli_* instead of mysql.

Comment: See the big, pink box near the top of http://php.net/mysql_query ? You might want to pay attention to that.

Comment: @Quentin That's a good idea, but I don't think that will solve his problem.

Comment: Test you query string `SELECT zagolovok FROM Title WHERE id = 5` directly in your database to ensure that data is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding or die(mysql_error()) to query and see what happens

```
$title_query = mysql_query($title_db_query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title_db_query = "SELECT zagolovok FROM Title WHERE id = 5";
```

This query selects the field zagolovok from the table Title, meaning that you have a table Title which has a column named zagolovok. It selects only one row since the id is probably an unique index. So it will select from the row with id 5 the data from the column zagolovok.

```
$title_query = mysql_query ($title_db_query);
```

This will send the query to the database and the returned result is saved in the variable $title_query. If the query wasn't successful it will return false.

```
while($row_title = mysql_fetch_array($title_query))
{  
    echo $row_title['zagolovok']; 
}
```

This you should use like this : `mysql_fetch_array($title_query, MYSQL_ASSOC)`.
It will return an associative array (the key of the array will be the name of the column) or `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)` will return an array with numeric keys.

Also I recommend you to use mysqli instead of mysql or PDO if you're quite familiar with objects. From what I know PDO performs fastest. Good luck.